# Convex Combination of 3 point in R2 and Triangle

Tags: convex-analysis

I am new to convex combination, and I am quite amazed by some easy result.

I know that convex combination of 2 points($P_1P_2$) in $R^2$ is all points in the line segment $P_1P_2$.

And then I see a result that convex combination of 3 points $P_1P_2P_3$, which is not in a line, is all points in the triangle $\bigtriangleup P_1P_2P_3$. It is a reasonable result, but I want to see how people prove it.

Can anyone provide a proof?

Comment: What's your definition for being in a triangle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The coefficients that arise in an affine combination of three 2D points are called *barycentric coordinates*. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinates_(mathematics)) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarycentricCoordinates.html) for more information.

These coordinates actually represent the (signed) areas of triangles, as the references explain. When a point is inside a triangle, the three relevant areas are all positive, so the barycentric coordinates correspond to a convex combination.

The references provide all the details, but a simple argument is as follows:

Suppose we have a triangle with vertices $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$, $\mathbf{C}$, 
and consider the convex combination 
$\mathbf{P} = u\mathbf{A} + v\mathbf{B} + w\mathbf{C}$, where $u,v,w $ are in the interval $[0,1]$ and $u+v+w=1$.

Define a point $\mathbf{Q}$ by
$$
\mathbf{Q} = \frac{v}{v+w}\mathbf{B} + \frac{w}{v+w}\mathbf{C}
$$
Clearly $\mathbf{Q}$ is on the line segment (the triangle edge) $\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C}$. But then
$$
\mathbf{P} = 
u\mathbf{A} + (v+w)\mathbf{Q} = u\mathbf{A} + (1-u)\mathbf{Q} 
$$
So, $\mathbf{P}$ is on the line segment $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{Q}$, and therefore it lies inside the triangle $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C}$.

If you're interested, the extension to three-dimensional space is easy: convex combinations give you the points inside a tetrahedron.

Comment: I saw the two links you provided, but they just give a conclusion. could you please explain it in more detail, thank you.

Comment: @user2262504 -- please see additions to my answer.

Comment: @user2262504 -- By the way, I see that you have asked 23 questions, but you have not accepted a single answer. You might get more answers (and better answers) if you start accepting some of them.

Comment: thank you. I did forget to mark the answer, I didn't know this before.

Answer (score 1):

A naive approach to picture the truth of the statment:

Consider the set of all convex combinations

$C = \left\lbrace\alpha_{1}x_{1} + \alpha_{2}x_{2} + \alpha_{3}x_{3}\right| \alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}+\alpha_{3}=1\rbrace$.

And imagine what happens if $\alpha_{1} = 0$ and $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2} \in (0,1]$, we must have a line segment joining $x_{2}$ to $x_{3}$. In the same way, we construct a segmente line joining $x_{1}$ to $x_{3}$ and $x_{1}$ to $x_{2}$. Then we have constructed the boundary of the triangle in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, in the cases where $\alpha_{i} \in (0,1)$ the points lie in the interior.